# Export iBook collections from an iPad to PC

Tags: ipad, books, pc

I have 1500 books, which are PDF and DRM-Free, organized in collections, and need to transfer them to a PC with the same organization.

Is possible to export iBook collections from an iPad to PC?

Comment: Hi, my books are in pdf drm free

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  There's many answers on this site about saving PDF files from iBooks to your computer.  Please search for those and try the answers already given.  If those don't work, [edit] your question with what you tried so we don't propose things that didn't work for you.